# React SocketIO dynamic connections based on data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, react-hooks

So, i'm stumbling upon this question and I can't wrap my head around it.

I have multiple endpoints, for example:
 - "/foo1"
 - "/bar2"
 - "/faz3"
 - "/boo4"

How would I be able to automatically manage these connections in react?

For example:

```js
// File: EndpointManager.js

const [allEndpoints, setAllEndpoints] = useState([]);
const [activeEndpoints, setActiveEndpoints] = useState(["/foo1", "/faz3"]);

useEffect(() => {
  // I fetch the endpoints here

  return () => setAllEndpoints([]);
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
   if (!allEndpoints.length > 0) return;
   // Some code here to dynamically manage the socket connections on change, I need your help here
}, [activeEndpoints])
```

Now, I can connect dynamically with an array foreach and opening a new connection within that foreach, but that variable is stored temporarily (because it's a foreach). So I can't access it after the loop, even if I loop twice. How would I be able to manage these connections based on that array? *Or another solution which will work the way I want*

The problem I am facing is that I have no idea how I would be able to dynamically store these connections. I have thought of creating dynamic variables such as `socketFoo1`, `socketFaz3`, but I have no clue how to implement this. Please help me out here! :)

**TL;DR**

> *I want to accomplish dynamic websocket connections which can connect/disconnect based on an array/object/whatsoever*

Kind regards!